# Drag&Drop element into canvas from HTML

Tags: three.js

I've got a very trivial task to drag&drop the element from a gallery into the Three.js canvas.

Nothing seems tricky until I face the problem that when I drag the item and add it to the scene I cannot update the item's coordinates until I finish the drag&drop event

I already played around with all events that watch the mouse event `mousemove`, `drag`, `dragover` but the element is just stuck at the initial coordinates, the ones I applied in the `dragenter` event

```js
export const params = {
    devicePixelRatio: Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2),
    size: getSizeParams(),
    grid: {
        size: 20,
        divisions: 20,
    },
}

const itemProtos = ['Box', 'Sphere', 'Cone']

export const canvas = document.querySelector(`#canvas`)

const raycaster = new Raycaster()
const pointer = new Vector2()

const scene = new Scene()
const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(75, params.size.width / params.size.height, 0.1, 100)
camera.position.z = 5
camera.position.y = 2

/**
 * Variable for Drag&Drop - just created object that's being moved around
 */
let newObjectType = null
let newObject = null

/**
 * Groups
 */
export const itemGroup = new Group()
scene.add(itemGroup)

/**
 * Grid
 */
export const gridHelper = new GridHelper(params.grid.size, params.grid.divisions)
scene.add(gridHelper)

/**
 * Renderer
 */
const renderer = new WebGLRenderer({
    canvas,
    antialias: true,
})
renderer.setSize(params.size.width, params.size.height)
renderer.setPixelRatio(params.devicePixelRatio)

/**
 * Resizing updates to fit the screen
 */
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    params.size = getSizeParams()
    camera.aspect = params.size.width / params.size.height
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

    renderer.setSize(params.size.width, params.size.height)
    renderer.setPixelRatio()
})

canvas.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    canvas.style.cursor = 'grab'
})

/**
 * Controls
 */
const orbitControls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas)
orbitControls.enableDamping = true

orbitControls.addEventListener('start', () => {
    canvas.style.cursor = 'grabbing'
})

orbitControls.addEventListener('end', () => {
    canvas.style.cursor = 'grab'
})

const tick = () => {

    orbitControls.update()

    requestAnimationFrame(tick)

    renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

window.onload = tick

/**
 * Raycaster functions
 */
const refreshMouseCoords = (event) => {
    pointer.x = (event.clientX / params.size.width) * 2 - 1
    pointer.y = -(event.clientY / params.size.height) * 2 + 1
}

let currentIntersect = null
let currentPick = null

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
    refreshMouseCoords(event)

    raycaster.setFromCamera(pointer, camera)

    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(itemGroup.children, false)
    

    if(intersects.length && intersects[0].object instanceof Mesh) {

        if(!currentIntersect) {
            canvas.style.cursor = 'all-scroll'
            intersects[0].object.material.color.set('red')
            console.log(`mouse enter`)
        }

        if(currentIntersect && currentIntersect !== intersects[0].object) {
            currentIntersect.material.color.set('blue')
            intersects[0].object.material.color.set('red')
        }
        
        currentIntersect = intersects[0].object

    } else {

        if(currentIntersect) {
            console.log(`mouse leave`)
            currentIntersect.material.color.set('blue')
            canvas.style.cursor = 'grab'
        }

        currentIntersect = null

    }

    moveItem(currentPick)

})

/**
 * Function to move items around GridHelper
 */
const moveItem = (item) => {
    const intersectsGround = raycaster.intersectObject(gridHelper, false)

    if(item && intersectsGround[0]) {
        item.position.z = intersectsGround[0].point.z
        item.position.x = intersectsGround[0].point.x
    }
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    refreshMouseCoords(event)

    raycaster.setFromCamera(pointer, camera)

    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(itemGroup.children, false)

    if(intersects.length && intersects[0].object instanceof Mesh) {
        currentPick = intersects[0].object
    }

    if(currentIntersect) {
        canvas.style.cursor = 'all-scroll'
        orbitControls.enabled = false
    }

})

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {

    if(currentIntersect) {
        canvas.style.cursor = 'all-scroll'
        orbitControls.enabled = true
    }

    if(currentPick) {
        currentPick = null
    }

})

// *** Drag&Drop *** //
const gallery = document.querySelector(`#gallery`)

setGallery(itemProtos, gallery)

canvas.addEventListener('dragenter', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('Drag&Drop: dragenter')
    
    refreshMouseCoords(event)

    raycaster.setFromCamera(pointer, camera)

    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(gridHelper)

    if (intersects.length && newObjectType) {
        add3DEl(intersects[0].point, newObjectType, itemGroup)
    }
})

canvas.addEventListener('dragover', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation()

    if(newObject) {
        moveItem(newObject)
    }
})

function setGallery(itemProtos, gallery) {
    for (let i of itemProtos) {

        const el = createProto()

        gallery.appendChild(el)

        el.addEventListener('dragstart', function (event) {
            event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', i)
            newObjectType = i
        })

        el.addEventListener('dragend', function () {
            newObjectType = null
            newObject = null
        })

    }
}

function add3DEl({ x, z }, type = 'Box', scene) {

    const geometry = new itemObjects[`${type}Geometry`]()
    const material = new MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff }) // Shared material for all items
    material.wireframe = true
    const el = new Mesh(geometry, material)
    el.position.x = x
    el.position.y = type == 'Sphere' ? 1 : .5
    el.position.z = z
    el.userData.name = `${type}_${Date.now()}`

    newObject = el

    scene.add(el)

}
```

Here you can find a playgroud with what I've got so far: [Playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-q39ien?file=index.js)

Comment: @WestLangley, thanks for your correction! I've added a link to Blitz playground, could you shoot a look at my issue? Maybe you've got some ideas on how to make the moving

Comment: Did you ever get this example fully working? If so, could you post an update playground? Thanks.